# Porque usamos 'e/ou' e não 'ou/e'?

Tags: gramática

Ao construirmos uma frase em que pode ocorrer duas situações ou apenas uma acabamos utilizando e/ou, por exemplo:

```
Hoje eu vou correr e/ou andar de bicicleta.
```

O uso do e/ou é comum, entretanto gostaria de saber se é apenas costume ou se existe uma regra para utilizar 'e/ou' e não 'ou/e'.

Comment: Que eu saiba não existe nenhuma regra, além do mais o *slash* é ele próprio um **ou**. Existem mais casos onde usamos o *slash*, por exemplo "Logo queres/podes vir jantar a minha casa jantar?".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Usa-se "e/ou" em vez de "ou/e" porque se segue o modelo da forma inglesa *and/or*.

O uso do "e/ou" retira ambiguidade à frase, tendo o mesmo sentido de um "ou" inclusivo: hoje vou correr ou andar de bicicleta (ou fazer as duas coisas).

Consultar [Ciberdúvidas: Sobre o uso do e/ou](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/sobre-o-uso-de-eou/25398).

Comment: For your answer to be complete, you must quote the source and provide links.  Who said it follows the English model ?  When ?  Where ?

Comment: @Centaurus  The English model is mentioned in the linked entry of Ciberdúvidas: "Cabe, porém,  referir que este ou outros pareceres serão sempre controversos, porque o próprio modelo de  **e/ou**, que é and/or, tanto tem defensores como tem detractores no próprio mundo de língua inglesa".

Comment: E se começássemos a escrever ***eou***? Parece-me a barra tão deselegante. Haverá línguas que têm uma palavra para ***ou*** exclusivo*** e outra diferente paro o inclusivo?