# "E (ou)" em vez de "e/ou"

Tags: ortografia, pontuação

Meus professores me ensinaram a usar "e (ou)" em lugar do que chamaram de anglicismo do "e/ou". Mas buscas no Google não retornaram exemplos ou explicações, creio que por causa do mecanismo de correção ortográfica que normaliza muitas expressões comuns.

Há, ou houve, alguma recomendação formal nesse sentido (ou no sentido oposto)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ambos estão corretos, mas `e/ou` é bem mais difundido.

O uso do parênteses para indicar alternativa é bastante conhecido, por exemplo:

> É exigido que o(a) aluno(a) permaneça em silêncio.

Mas é interessante observar que, de acordo com o [Norma Culta](https://www.normaculta.com.br/parenteses/) (pessoalmente, não lembro de já ter encontrado esse exemplo), também nesse caso barras seriam aceitáveis:

> É exigido que o/a aluno/a permaneça em silêncio.

Não encontrei referência alguma condenando o uso do `e/ou`, pelo contrário, a única observação frequentemente feita é no sentido do uso, obviamente, dever ser o adequado, ou seja,

> A e/ou B

significa que **deve** ser possível ter:

- apenas A, e
- apenas B, e
- A *e* B simultaneamente.

Entre os que confirmam o uso de `e/ou` estão os linguistas Mafalda Antunes ([link](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/o-uso-de-e--ou/10189)) e Carlos Rocha ([link](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/sobre-o-uso-de-eou/25398)), e o professor D´Silvas Filho ([link](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/ainda-o-uso-da-barra-/14128)) no Ciberdúvidas, além dos sites [Norma Culta](https://www.normaculta.com.br/barra-obliqua/), [sualíngua](http://sualingua.com.br/2010/05/24/eou-valor-da-barra-inclinada/), [Jurisway](https://www.jurisway.org.br/v2/pergunta.asp?idmodelo=9888), [Dúvidas dicio](https://duvidas.dicio.com.br/uso-de-eou/), entre outros. E uma questão relacionada também já apareceu por aqui: [Porque usamos 'e/ou' e não 'ou/e'?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/749/2764).