# Uso da expressão "e/ou" em Portugal

Tags: expressões, português-europeu

Gostaria de esclarecer se é correto o uso escrito da expressão "e/ou" (com barra oblíqua) em português de Portugal. Já encontrei a expressão grafada "e ou" e "e(ou)". Qual é então a forma mais correta? Agradeço um esclarecimento.

Comment: António, já existe [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/5532/e-ou-em-vez-de-e-ou) sobre o assunto; e também [esta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/749/porque-usamos-e-ou-e-n%c3%a3o-ou-e) relacionada.

Comment: De notar que a pergunta relacionada tem uma resposta apenas sobre português brasileiro. Vou editar o título para o contexto europeu ficar mais óbvio e claro.

Comment: @ANeves, de qual é que estás a falar. Não encontro nenhuma observação restingindo qualquer dos posts ao português brasileiro. A resposta do stafusa à [primeira pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/5532/e-ou-em-vez-de-e-ou) apoia-se numa porção de gramáticos portugueses no Coberdúvidas. A minha única hesitação e votar como duplicata é que esta pergunta menciona a possibilidade "e ou", não tratada nas outras, embora tratada nalgumas das fontes indicadas.

Comment: @Jacinto, era essa mesmo, "a do stafusa à primeira pergunta"; escapou-me o link para o ciberdúvidas. Obrigado pela correção :)

Answer (score 2):

Ambos `e/ou` e `e(ou)` estão corretos, como exposto [nesta resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/5533/2764) minha, embora o primeiro (com a barra) seja mais frequente.

A construção `e ou`, que simplesmente justapõe duas conjunções de significados diferentes é, no mínimo, confusa, como também coloca a linguista portuguesa Mafalda Antunes no [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/o-uso-de-e--ou/10189):

> A barra indica opcionalidade de uso de cada uma das conjunções coordenativas: aditiva (e) ou disjuntiva (ou). A ausência de barra comprometeria a clareza desta opcionalidade.